# MongoDB aggregation neither $toString nor $convert works in projection stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to convert an integer field to string in my aggregation query.

What i tried to do is similar like this:

```
$project: 
{
    ConvertedField : {$toString: 123}
}
```

However it gives this error when I run the stage :

Unrecognized expression '$toString'

Mongo version is 4.0 and I also tried $convert but it gives the same error.

Why do I get this error and what can be solution for this problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: So what does `db.version()` from the `mongo` shell actually show you? Did you possibly "upgrade" this instance from an earlier version? If the first question shows you 4.x and the answer to the second is "yes" then check the [`setFeatureCompatibiltyVersion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) setting. Bottom line is you either are "not" running 4.x or your "upgrade" is missing a step.

Comment: Secondary version is 3.6. I just noticed it . Thanks a lot. Well, is it possible to solve the problem with any feature compatible with 3.6 ?

Comment: "Typcasting" does not really exist at all in versions earlier to 4.0. It's not really clear what you are actually trying to do in your question other than demonstrating a reported error. "Un-officially" you have pretty much always been able to convert "integers" to "string" via `$substr`.

Comment: I have an array of objects whose all properties(key,value) are string. And I have a field in integer (name it OrderId) . I want to filter my array with the rule that key property of the element equals to OrderId. But since their types are different (string and int) I cant do this.

Comment: Comments are not the place to ask your question. [Asking Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) is where you ask questions. I would strongly suggest posting a new question and be clear about the details for what you want to do, of course noting you cannot use MongoDB 4 features. The original question you asked was simply "why does this not work?" and changing the topic pollutes the conversation. Ask a new Question instead.

Comment: You are right. I am sorry. I asked new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119588/how-to-perform-type-casting-in-mongodb-aggregation-query-in-version-3-6

Answer (score 0):

It is probably that you're running an old MongoDB version, however you can still achieve that by using a little tweak `$substr`

```
  $project: {
      convertedField: {
        $substr: ["$fieldYouWantToConvert", 0, 10]
      },
    },
```